# How to output oracle query result into a text file in windows?

Tags: database, oracle

The query will produce a **large data set** **(4 columns and ~ 6 million rows)**. I tried the query below on smaller data but it wrote the query itself to the text file not the query results:

```
spool test.txt
SELECT a.ID, a.COLOR,a.TYPE,b.DESC
FROM TABLE_1 a
left join TABLE_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
spool off
```

what's the most efficient way to extract the data above from the Oracle database? I will be running the query in Production database and would like to extract the data in the most efficient way. Other than `spool` function, anything else to try?

Comment: Did this **only** write the query to `test.txt`, and not the result of the query? That is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Create An Oracle Directory and use UTL_FILE to write files into it.

For any further clarifccations don't hesitate to contact me here again!

Ted

e.g.

```
create directory logfile as 'd:\logfile'; -- must have priv to do this

declare
  vFile utl_file.file_type;
begin
  vFile := utl_file.fopen(logfile ,'syslog','w'); -- w is write. This returns file handle
  utl_file.put(vFile,'Start Logfile'); -- note use of file handle vFile
  utl_file.fclose(vFile); -- note use of file handle vFile
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be a [bulk export.](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/tools/rtoolsimport91458.html)

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY 
   ('SELECT a.ID, a.COLOR, a.TYPE, b.DESC
       FROM TABLE_1 a left join TABLE_2 b on a.ID=b.ID',
    '/path/to/test.txt',',','"','UTF-8');
```

Comment: I tried the above but got the error "Error starting at line : 1 in command - CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY 
   ('SELECT a.ID, a.COLOR, a.TYPE, b.DESC
       FROM TABLE_1 a left join TABLE_2 b on a.ID=b.ID',
    '/path/to/test.txt',',','"','UTF-8');

Comment: UPDATE- I tried to run the first line by itself and got: "SQL Error: ORA-06576:not a valid function or procedure name". I'm using ORACLE SQL Developer version 4.1.0.19

Comment: Maybe some package is missing, I linked the specs in my answer.

Comment: SYSCS is not a schema installed by default with an Oracle DB.